# validate xml against xsd reading from mysql in mirth connect

Tags: mysql, xml, xsd

Validation of the xml file against xsd from file location is working fine, but when we validate the xml against xsd from mysql location, it is not working.
     this is channel

```
var SQLText = "";
var ResultSet = "";
var dbConn =GetCtDexConn();


function validateHL7Msg(incomingXml)
{
  var validMessage = true;
  var HL7xml = new XML(SerializerFactory.getSerializer('HL7V2').toXML(incomingXml));
  logger.info('HL7xml '+HL7xml);
  try
   {
    //SQLText = "select DEXPropXML from dbo.DEXUserProperties where Property = 'ClaimTrakValidationXml'";
    SQLText = "select * from TestXML";
    ResultSet = dbConn.executeCachedQuery(SQLText);
        while (ResultSet.next()){
        var clobdata = ResultSet.getClob(1);
        var cloblength = clobdata.length();
        var StringXML = clobdata.getSubString(1, cloblength);
        var Validations = new XML(StringXML);
        logger.info('Validations: '+Validations);
        }
     } 
   finally
    {
    dbConn.close();
    }   
    var schemaFactory = Packages.javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    var schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(Validations);
    for each(mshxml in HL7xml)
    {
    var reader = new Packages.java.io.StringReader(mshxml);
    var xmlFile = new Packages.javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(reader);
    // create a new validator for the schema
    var validator = schema.newValidator();
    try {
        // validates the message
         validator.validate(xmlFile);
       // valid message
       logger.info('valid');
    } catch (err) {
    // invalid message
    logger.error(err.toString());
    logger.info("error")
    }

 return validMessage;
 }
}
/************Main Flow*****************/
var incomingXml = msg;
if(validateHL7Msg(incomingXml))
{
logger.info("message processed");
}
else
{
logger.info("message discarded");
}
```

Comment: XML schema is typically a very stable thing. I'm just wondering why not to place schemas to a folder? Other approach is to download schemas from the database to a folder first and then apply schema validation.